# C# WindowsForms - Send textbox from form1 to form2 on visual studio

Tags: c#, visual-studio, textbox, send

i have 2 forms on visual studio,

```
form1 have textbox1.text
form2, have textbox2.text and btnSave
```

obs: form2 open when i click on another button on form 1:

```
Form new = new form2();
           nova.Show();
```

how can i send textbox2 content from form2 to form1 (textbox1) clicking on btnSave ?
What code will be necessary inside this click button event.

Thanks

Comment: Add a public property to form1.

Comment: Add public static variable to Form1 and you can access it from anywhere.

Comment: Where are you sending the textbox data on form 2 to form 1?  Another textbox?  What have you tried so far?  Please post your code.

Comment: if you add non static public property or variable then you need to pass instance of form1 to form2.

Comment: How i can add public static variable ?

Comment: You should explain which relationship exists between the two forms. Is Form1 the parent of Form2 (meaning inside the code of Form1 you instantiate a new Form2() and show it modally (Form2.ShowDialog()) or modeless (Form2.Show())?

Comment: @Dilshod That's pretty terrible design, and doing so for any non-trivially sized project results in a mess of spaghetti that just can't be sorted out.

Comment: @Steve Edited, for better understanding

Comment: @Servy I posted 2 comments in there. Could you be more specific which one are you talking about.

Comment: @Dilshod It applies to both, actually, although the first more so than the second.

Comment: If you have solved the issue, please post an *answer*; do not edit the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

researching i was able to make it work, lost some hours but now all is perfect, this is code that worked for me:

On form2:

```
public partial class form2 : Form
    {
        private string nome;
        public string passvalue
        {
            get { return nome; }
            set { nome = value; }
        }
```

form2, button save:

```
private void btnSalvar_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            passvalue = txtMetragemcubica.Text;
            this.Hide();
        }
```

on form1 (this button open form2):

```
private void btnMetragemcubica_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            form2 n = new form2();
            n.ShowDialog();
            txtMetragem.Text = n.passvalue
        }
```

Now it work this way: Open on form 1, then i click on button btnMetragemcubica and form2 open, then i insert values on different textbox and have result on txtMetragemcubica, when i click on save button (btnSalvar) it close form2 and send value to form1 in txtMetragem textbox.

Working perfect here, hope help another persons too. 
Anyway thanks for all help

Answer (score 3):

Try this please:
Step1: Create a constructor for form2 class as below:

```
 public Form2(string strTextBox)
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            label1.Text = strTextBox;
        }
```

Step2: Instantiate form2 class in form1’s button click event handler as below:

```
 private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Form2 obj1 = new Form2(textBox1.Text);
            obj1.Show();
            this.Hide();
        }
```

Comment: This not worked, how form2 will send txt content to form1 ? should be using button, but, its confusing..

Comment: here form1 send text to form2 in my example. and there is a constructor in form2. so when initialize form2 send to constructor the value as param.its work for me. textBox1 is a text box in form1 where value given. button1 in form1. in form2 label1 is a label to show the value from form2. and its working for me

Comment: I was looking for this piece of code alot. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Create an event on your second form that can be fired when the form is saved:

```
public event Action Saved;
```

Then create a property on that form that allows the textbox's text to be accessed:

```
public string SomeTextValue //TODO: rename to meaningful name
    { get{ return textbox2.Text;} }
```

Then you need to fire off the `Saved` event when you save your form:

```
if(Saved != null)
    Saved();
```

Then when you first create the form in `Form1` attach an event handler to that event:

```
Form2 child = new Form2();
child.Saved += () => textbox1.Text = child.SomeTextValue;
child.Show();
```

Note that if you are also closing the second form right when you save it then you don't need a custom event, you can just utilize `FormClosing` instead.

Comment: in form2 i added: public Action event Saved; i have 3 errors, then i clicked on saved and pressed "generate class for Saved", then remain 2 errors: "Error 1 Invalid token 'event' in class, struct, or interface member declaration" and "Error 2 Invalid token ';' in class, struct, or interface member declaration", after solve that i will continue follow your steps

Comment: @felipeSalomao Yep, it compiles and runs just fine for me.  `public class Form2 { public event Action Saved; }` compiles exactly as is.

Comment: Now all is ok with public event Action Saved; problem was that before i not created public class Form2 { public event Action Saved; }, so it was on wrong place because of this i had error, second step worked too: public string SomeTextValue (i created this on form2 too), third step not worked, had about 7 errors, where i should put it ? on button click of open form2 in form1 right ?

Comment: @felipeSalomao The only code that you're *adding* is the one line in the middle that actually attaches the event handler to `Saved`.  You should already have the first and third lines of code in your program *somewhere*.  Find that somewhere, and add that one line between the two of them.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/28927/discussion-between-felipe-salomao-and-servy)

Comment: I was able to make all steps without any error, but problem is that it simple not work, what button should i press to send textbox from form2 to form1 ? we dont created any button for that

Comment: @felipeSalomao Then fire the event when you want to.  I edited in an example of how to do so.